# Passing Optional parameters while calling SQL SERVER's stored procedure in pymssql

Tags: python, sql-server, pymssql

I am using pymssql library to retrieve data from MS SQL Server using stored procedures. 
While passing Mandatory parameters, i have no issues.

How to pass optional parameters in pymssql ?

My stored proc has 5 parameters, 2 are mandatory and 3 are optional.

```
procedure_connection.cursor.callproc('PROCEDURE_NAME', (mandatory_parameter_1,mandatory_parameter_2))
```

In what order I have to pass optional parameters ?

```
procedure_connection.cursor.callproc('PROCEDURE_NAME', (mandatory_parameter_1,mandatory_parameter_2,optional_parameter_1))   

procedure_connection.cursor.callproc('PROCEDURE_NAME', (mandatory_parameter_1,mandatory_parameter_2,optional_parameter_2))   

procedure_connection.cursor.callproc('PROCEDURE_NAME', (mandatory_parameter_1,mandatory_parameter_2,optional_parameter_3))   

procedure_connection.cursor.callproc('PROCEDURE_NAME', (mandatory_parameter_1,mandatory_parameter_2,optional_parameter_1,optional_parameter_2,optional_parameter_3,))

procedure_connection.cursor.callproc('PROCEDURE_NAME', (mandatory_parameter_1,mandatory_parameter_2))
```

I want to pass optional parameters, and ensure that the right parameter is set instead of something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call the stored procedure with the "EXEC" command, which allows you to identify what parameters you want to use:

```
sql = """EXEC PROCEDURE_NAME @mandatory_parameter1=?, @mandatory_parameter2=?, @optional_parameter3=?"""

params = (mandatory_parameter1_value, mandatory_parameter1_value, optional_parameter3_value)

procedure_connection.cursor.execute(sql, params)
```